# Submit multiple forms with one click to an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

would anybody be able to help me with some code to submit all of my forms to an iframe with a single click? In my actual code I have 5+ forms that all need to be submitted with one button press. I have tested submitting one form and it submits correctly to the iframe. There must be a simple way, possibly some jQuery to submit all of the forms in a loop?

```
<form name="1398694471249" method="post" action="WuFoo.aspx" target="formresponse" id="1398694471249">
  <input type="hidden" name="Title" id="Title" value="Mr">
  <input type="hidden" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="Oliver">
  <input type="hidden" name="Surname" id="Surname" value="Clark">
  <input type="hidden" name="DateOfBirth" id="DateOfBirth" value="19861230">
</form>

<form name="1528632259273" method="post" action="WuFoo.aspx" target="formresponse" id="1528632259273">
  <input type="hidden" name="Title" id="Title" value="Mrs">
  <input type="hidden" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="Sarah">
  <input type="hidden" name="Surname" id="Surname" value="Bloggs">
  <input type="hidden" name="DateOfBirth" id="DateOfBirth" value="19750622">
</form>

<iframe name='formresponse' width='100%' height='100'></iframe>

<!-- I want to press this button and submit all forms within the iframe -->

<button type="submit">Submit both forms to iframe</button>
```

As you can see I have two forms (these are dynamically generated from previously captured data in localStorage) so there will be quite a few forms. I was told I can submit multiple forms to an iframe I'm just not sure how. All help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you want to wait the result of the iframe post before each other submission ?

Comment: You have to use AJAX to submit more than one form at a time. Normal form submission reloads the page.

Comment: @Barmar : Submission in an iframe don't reload anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
$("form").each(function() {
  $(this).submit();
});
```

If you don't care about the contents of the iframe, you can make a fake iframe and load it there:

```
$("form").each(function() {

  var $form = $(this);
  var $iframe = $("<iframe name='temporary-iframe'></iframe>");

  var oldTarget = $form.prop("target");
  $form.prop("target", "temporary-iframe");

  $("body").append($iframe);
  $form.submit();
  $iframe.remove();
  $form.prop("target", oldTarget);

});
```

The above example has a few small performance issues. If this runs too slowly for you (which will probably happen only if you have a *ton* of forms:

```
$("form").each(function() {
  var oldTarget = this.target;
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  this.target = iframe.name = "temporary-iframe";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  $(this).submit();
  $(iframe).remove();
  this.target = oldTarget;
});
```

If you have issues where only the *last* form submits, that probably means that form #2 stomps on form #1 before it can finish, then #3 stomps on #2, then #4 on #3, et cetera. If you don't care about the contents of the iframe, you can use the above solution. If you *do* care about the iframe's contents, you'll need to come up with some algorithm for "which iframe do I show?"

Comment: Fabulous, I've got it all working nicely now. However I need some kind of alert or progress bar to inform the user that the forms are still submitting, or done submitting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use Ajax you will have to post each form to an individual Iframe. If you use a single iframe you'll likely cancel the submit before it completes by submitting secondary forms.